# How do I breach the castle?

Tags: candy-box

I can't figure out how to get though the castle entrance, that darn ball keeps teloporting me to the start! any advice?

Comment: looked though and didn't see that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep upgrading your sword as much as possible, you should also eat a lot of candies which affects your HP and damage.

Comment: so, just sit and wait until I earn enough?

Comment: Pretty much yeah, there's no other option.
Oh right, I forgot about **Berserk Potions** but those might still not be enough to catch up with the speed of the "missle".

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a cloning potion. Your clone will kill the GUArds and KNIgths. The way is free to the entrance.
I use this strategy to get a lot of candies, until I drop to 100 PV :o)

Comment: Anonymous comment: "of course you cant make cloning potions until you get the cauldron which means you've already beat this stage"